# Outlook does not import location correctly from iCal feed

Tags: icalendar, street-address, postal-code, microsoft-exchange

I have an iCal feed. Outlook does not display location as a clickable link. In google calendar and Mac it works fine.

from the feed I get the following output

```
LOCATION;VVENUE=L-ID4:Q-Factory Atlantisplein 1 1093 NE Amsterdam
```

which works fine in google and Mac calendars: the location is displayed as a link to (Google) Maps

For Outlook I state

```
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONDISPLAYNAME:Q-Factory
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONSTREET:Atlantisplein 1
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONPOSTALCODE:1093 NE
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONCITY:Amsterdam
X-MICROSOFT-LOCATIONCOUNTRY:NL
```

In Outlook calendar, the location is displayed but has no clickable link to Google Maps.

When I make an event manually in Outlook cal, it does make the location clickable.

How can I do the same from iCal feed?